# Set Invisible a layout , which is over layed on a tabs content view

Tags: android, tabs

I have an activity that contains a tab view and a few buttons to display certain layouts on click. The tabs content and the contents to be displayed on click of buttons share the same content area.On create my Tab view contents works perfectly fine. When I click on the button and inflate a layout on tabs content the layout appears fine. Now again clicking on tab view I want to make that layout invisible.

```
    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
    import android.widget.TabWidget;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends TabActivity{
TabHost mTabHost;

ImageView contactBtn;
LinearLayout popupLayout;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.saintgobain_home);

    ((TabWidget)findViewById(android.R.id.tabs)).setOnClickListener(onclickListener);

    popupLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.popups);

    contactBtn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mailBtn);
    contactBtn.setOnClickListener(onclickListener);

    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


    Intent BuildingIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeScreen.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), getResources().getString(R.string.BuildingType_str), BuildingIntent);
    Intent AppIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, ApplicationList.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), getResources().getString(R.string.Application_str), AppIntent);
    Intent productIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, ProductScreen.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), getResources().getString(R.string.Product_str), productIntent);
    Intent intentDealer = new Intent().setClass(this, DealersActivity.class);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), getResources().getString(R.string.Dealer_str), intentDealer);
}
private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, Intent intentAndroid) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intentAndroid);
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_text, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}

OnClickListener onclickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.mailBtn:
            Log.d("","mailbtn");

                //((FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                View view =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact, null);
                popupLayout.addView(view,params);
                popupLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                    
            break;  
        case android.R.id.tabs:
            if(popupLayout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE);
            {
                popupLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};
}
```

I am not sure how to make the pop up layout invisible when i  click on the tab widget again.
Please Help..
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried popupLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)? Remember you can use View.GONE if you want to let it completely disappear and reset offsets of remaining widgets

Comment: I have tried it. You can see in the code on the onClickListener of tab i check for the layouts visibility and then set it to invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably TabWidget do not listen to click... You need set onClickListener in tabs... Like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry was away on weekend.. In the above lines I get error on getTabWidget(). If i try tabs.getChildAt(i) I do not get any error but nothing happens when i run. Can You explain significance of getTabWidget().

Comment: Since I am creating the tabViews at runtime ,tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount() gives 0.

Comment: you need write this after setupTab